# Postgres autocomplete and full text search

Tags: postgresql, autocomplete, full-text-search

I need to create suggestion autocomplete for all the columns of a table in a single searchbox using postgres database.
I have a search autocomplete in web page and need to autosuggest the options. All columns are varchar.

For searching I am using the approach like

```
select * from userschema.user_details where to_tsvector(user_details::text) @@ to_tsquery('text:*')
```

But I am facing an issue getting the options for autocomplete.
Is there a way of searching the  tsvector and getting all the options that match a criteria.
Something like getting text* options from all the words of tsvector so that I can use them for autosuggest.

I am thinking of storing the contents of tsvector into a column. 
Is there a way of fetching autosuggest words from same?